# MobFox very low CPC and no eCPM control anywhere

Tags: android, networking, mobfox

i'm using MobFox succesfully but i'm observing a very low CPC, less than 0,01$ and i think this is not a normal working. The support from them they do not give me any answer for this. I want to increase it by mediation, and MobFox says that you can control de eCPM but i'm not able to find out it through the menu... Where is it??

Should i change my network? Apart from Admob what is the best choice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure CPM values for different networks by opening the **Publisher menu**, selecting **Manage Monetization** and clicking the **Create New Item** button. I have already tried that and found that MobFox does not come even close to AdMob regarding CPMs. I have also had a terrible experience with their support (it took them more than 7 days to get a reply for several tickets).

I am using AdMob, MobFox and InMobi at the moment. AdMob is by far the best (giving CPMs over $1.00). MobFox and InMobi give CPMs between $0.20 and $0.34. I will stop using MobFox because of the lack of support. I am still testing with InMobi - CPMs are not so good but at least their support replies within a day and they promised that they can provide CPMs that can compete AdMob.

Comment: Until now, are you still using MobFox and InMobi? 
Have they ever reached a competitive level relative to admob?